# iOS TableView Reuse would load a lot of subviews to cell

Tags: ios, tableview

I used the following code to implement cell for every row at index path:
But the problem is when I scroll the tableView, the cell will load a lot of UIImageView *itemimageview in one cell in one line, I tried use

```
   for (UIImageView *sView in cell.subviews) {
        [sView removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

but it would remove all subviews of one cell. How to solve this problem?...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];
    static NSString *CheckMarkCellIdentifier = @"CheckMarkCellIdentifier";

    //dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier --
    // Returns a reusable table-view cell object located by its identifier.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CheckMarkCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CheckMarkCellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    /*
    for (UIImageView *sView in cell.subviews) {
        [sView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    */
    UIImageView *itemimageview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 232, 54)];
    itemimageview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[tabsImageArray objectAtIndex:row]];

    itemimageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:itemimageview];
    [itemimageview release];

    UIImageView *dictIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 18, 30, 30)];
    dictIcon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dictionary_icon.png"];
    dictIcon.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dictIcon];
    [dictIcon release];

    UILabel *dictNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 23, 100, 21)];
    dictNameLabel.text = dictName;
    dictNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    dictNameLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    dictNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dictNameLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dictNameLabel];
    [dictNameLabel release];


    //cell.textLabel.text = [tabsImageArray objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.accessoryType = (row == oldRow && lastIndexPath != nil) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider running through and checking [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] to check whether the view is the right type of view to remove.

Also consider tagging the views with the UIView tag property, so you can add the subviews once, and then won't have to recreate them with reuse.

Here is how you would do this:

```
#define ImageViewOneTag 1001
#define ImageViewTwoTag 1002

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    static NSString *CellID = @"CellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];

    UIImageView *imageViewOne = nil;
    UIImageView *imageViewTwo = nil;

    if (cell) {
        // You've caught a reusable cell. Fetch the image views by their tag.

        imageViewOne = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:ImageViewOneTag];
        imageViewTwo = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:ImageViewTwoTag];
    } else {
        // You haven't got a reusable cell. Make one, and make and add the image views to the contentView.

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellID];

        imageViewOne = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
        [imageViewOne setTag:ImageViewOneTag];

        imageViewTwo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
        [imageViewTwo setTag:ImageViewTwoTag];

        UIView *contentView = cell.contentView;
        [contentView addSubview:imageViewOne];
        [contentView addSubview:imageViewTwo];
    }

    // By this stage, you've either retrieved a reusable cell, or you've made a new one. Either way, imageViewOne and imageViewTwo now have a reference to the views you mean.
    imageViewOne.image = *imageOneForRow*;
    imageViewTwo.image = *imageTwoForRow*;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to tag the views, can you tell me how to do this ? I am really fresh for tableView development.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using custom table view cell, just create a cocoa touch class which inherits uitableviewcell.